# Is there any other category besides prose and verse, for classification of literature according to format?

Tags: terminology

Prose and verse are two ways of classifying types of literature, is there a third category for the classification of literature according to format?

For example, in which category a graphic novel/comic book would fall?

Comment: See also: [writers.se]

Comment: @kris yes, I checked there too can't find it there either

Comment: Certainly there are many ways to classify literature, depending on your interests and prejudices.

Comment: In terms of "format", a long epic poem from Homer is certainly different from a Shakespeare sonnet.  And there are many other variations on poetry -- rhyming, blank verse, free verse.  In terms of prose, there are short stories, novels, phone books, Sears catalogs.  There's a whole universe out there.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a graphic novel or comic book or picture story is a relatively new form of the narrative genre. Normally the texts below the pictures are in normal language (prose), but there are also picture stories which use verse, i.e. language with rhyme and repetitive rhythmic patterns. The picture stories of Wilhelm Busch use verses, e.g. Max and Moritz. And picture stories can be fiction or non-fiction. You can tell historical events in picture stories.

Answer (score 0):

*Prose* and *verse* are the main groupings of English literature and can be further divided into categories *fiction* and *non-fiction*. A graphic novel/comic book would most likely fall under *fiction*.